# NEXT Image not Loading in production

Tags: next.js

I am using NEXT to build my web app. During my dev server, everything runs smoothly and all images appear as expected but when I run `next build` and then `next start` the image disappears in the dev server.

Not sure why this is happening can someone help me?

My folder structure is as shown below:

```
- public
---- pictures
------ icons
-------- iphone
---------- phone1.png
```

And here's how I put it in my component:

```
<div className={classes['stack-phone-v1']}>
              <Image
                alt={'phone-image-1'}
                height={567}
                width={284}
                src='/pictures/icon/iphone/phone1.png'
              />
            </div>
```

Comment: I have had this happen to me before, couldn't find out why, but the solution I came up with was to import the image like this: `import phone1 from "../public/pictures/icon/iphone/phone1.png"` and just use `phone1` as the src. I hope someone answers with an explanation to why this happens sometimes

Comment: Hmm, yeah right thanks for a quick fix though even I want a proper explanation to why it's not working the other way round

Comment: Yes! I also would like to see a proper explanation on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Make sure to follow the casing as it is, the fileName must be typed exactly similar to what it is and that would very likely solve your
> issue. No extra whitespaces, no additional symbols only file name as
> it is.**

On following up with other forums, I realized this was a very silly mistake from my side. While running images in dev server the casing doesn't matter, my image was `iphone.PNG` and I was reading it as `iphone.png`.

This is really important as it goes undetected in dev server and in production it won't load. I have seen a huge github thread for the same and suspect that this is the cause:

Generally when you see your files getting loaded but some of them not loading make sure all of them match casing exactly as they are named. Changing the import statement resolved my error. I hope this goes helpful to someone who may face same issue in future.

I just changed:

`src='/pictures/icon/iphone/phone1.png'`
to
`src='/pictures/icon/iphone/phone1.PNG'`

as original filename was `phone1.PNG`

Comment: Awesome! This problem with Nextjs has been plaguing a few of my projects for a while, went and looked and turns out there were some capitalization differences. Really sucks the dev servers don't alert you to this.

Answer (score 7):

Try Using

```
<Image
   unoptimized
/>
```

This worked for me as the optimized request was failing on production.

Comment: It worked for me, but can anyone give an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Try install `npm i next-images` and
add `next-images` to `next.config.js` file.

```js
const withImage=require('next-images')
module.exports = withImage()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and am able to solve it  by not leaving empty space " " at the end of the image path ` {

```
    name: 'Sunday Afolayan',
    imagePath: '/assets/team/Sunday-Afolayan.png ',
    title: 'Member'
}`
```

and am able to solve it by removing the empty space at the end of .png

` {

```
    name: 'Sunday Afolayan',
    imagePath: '/assets/team/Sunday-Afolayan.png',
    title: 'Member'
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in there, use `/icons` instead of `/icon`.

Comment: This appears to just by a typo in their folder structure, based on their subsequent answer. Given this, since this doesn’t answer the original question, this would be better handled as a suggested edit to the question, not as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

change from `src='/pictures/icon/iphone/phone1.png'` to `src='pictures/icon/iphone/phone1.png'`

Comment: Using `src='/pictures/icon/iphone/phone1.png'` is the right way to reference an image from the `public` folder in Next.js. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving.

Comment: @juliomalves, after built still see `src='/pictures/icon/iphone/phone1.png'` in index.html it will go to root that why its not working, so `src='pictures/icon/iphone/phone1.png'` or `src='./pictures/icon/iphone/phone1.png'` will work.

Comment: OP has the images in the `public` folder, "going to the root" will work. See the link I posted above.